# API Key Problem by moving App between Firebase Projects

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-play-services, project

I have moved my Flutter App in Firebase from one Project to another new Project and replaced previous `google-services.json` with the new one. Then I tried the App it was still connected to the previous project, all data was created in the old project, even if I have deleted the app from the old project. I couldn't find a solution to fix it so I deleted the old firebase project and cleared all caches. Then the App started to return `API is Invalid` errors. I made sure that I dont have any multiple files or they API is written somewhere else a well. without the new `google-services.json` it returns the error `No API Key was found` so it seems to be right placed.

I ran out of ideas how to fix it. Did I miss anything?

Comment: Did you try to run the firebase setup all over again?

Comment: Yes I did and just did it again to make sure. But didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

I was having the same error and I solved it by deleting the build folder and then running flutter package

Answer (score -1):

The only way to solve it was to change my package name and create a new App in my project. I guess the problem is internal at firebase that the old app didn't get properly deleted in the previous project.